# Plotting time and value using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to make a simple plot which includes time and values.

Dataframe looks like this:

```
    Time       Value    Notes
0   16:16:19    0.0     NaN
1   16:16:24    1.568   NaN
2   16:16:29    2.654   NaN
3   16:16:34    8.54    NaN
4   16:16:39    7.585   NaN
```

Type of the data frame:

```
Time           object
Value          float64
Notes          object
dtype: object
```

I am trying to plot it as below:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(df['Time'], df['Value'])

plt.show()
```

And I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a float
```

The method works fine for other data but I am getting error on this particular dataframe. How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Is the column `Notes` of importance for this question? I cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: What do you get when run `df.drop("Notes", 1).plot('Time', 'Value')` ?

Comment: Thanks, but I do need the notes column as it does have relevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have *Time* column as **string**, so first convert it to *datetime*:

```
df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time)
```

Then I executed your code and got quite normal plot:

[image]

In case of problems consider also upgrading your *Pandas* and/or *matplotlib* versions.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, I was just focusing on value rather than time. I can plot the figure, however, it also added the date in the time column. So, I tried to extract just time using; `df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time).dt.time`
but now I get this error: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time'

Comment: Read about *DateFormatter*, or other formatters available in *matplotlib*. The idea is to format each *x* axis value keeping only the time part.